# How to solve Elementor insert error in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have made a website in WP a year ago with Elementor and now I have to make some modifications. I updated the WP, theme, and plugins to latest. When I would like to add a new section or duplicate an existing element with the elementor editor, it does nothing. I can attach new components to the end, but not able to edit the already existing blocks.

Comment: Have you tried reaching out to the developer of the Elementor plugin yet? If not, then it might be a good idea to contact them as they can surely help you debug the issue: [Elementor Support Forum on WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/elementor/).

Answer (score 0):

So it was a bit confusing. The newer version does not support deep nesting of inner sections, I had to delete one level, so it is perfectly fine now.